# Externalize domainString Xamarin (android)

Tags: exception, xamarin, dns

I'm writing an app in Xamarin and was wondering if it's possible to externalize my strings I use in exceptions.

For example if I write in my code

```
throw new Exception("This is an error");
```

How can I externalize the errormessag "this is an error" ?

I already tried something like this :

```
throw new Exception("@string/errormessage")
```

and added errormessage to the Strings.xml file, but that didn't work.
Does anybody know if this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is in your `values\Strings.xml`:

```
<string name="stackoverflow">StackOverflow Custom Exception String</string>
```

You can use it as your custom exception message via:

```
button.Click += delegate {
   throw new Exception(this.Resources.GetString(Resource.String.stackoverflow));
};
```

Comment: Okay, so I've got to pass the Resources to my domain classes. Thank you for the reply! (I thought there would be a cleaner solution)

Comment: @Bosiwow Yes, if you look at the generated C# code for the Android resources, you will see how things are wrapped by the code generator @ `Resource.designer.cs`